# Solve $-0.2^{2019} \times 5^{2020} $ without calculator

Tags: arithmetic

This is a question extracted by my Mathematics test and I got wrong on it because my calculator cannot solve problems that huge. I want to know how to solve the question above ***without*** calculator.

Don't know which tag should be used, sorry!

Comment: Note: $0.2=\frac 15$ Done.

Comment: You should learn the [basic rules of exponentiation](https://mathinsight.org/exponentiation_basic_rules) then you can easily solve the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first you multiply $-0.2^{2019}\cdot{5}^{2020}$ by $-0.2$. And whatever number you get from that, you can divide it by $-0.2$ to get the result.

$-0.2^{2020}\cdot{5}^{2020}$ is equal to $(-1)^{2020}$ (you can multiply bases of exponents if they are raised to the same power) and $(-1)^{2020}$ is equal to $1$. And $1$ divided by $-0.2$ is equal to $-5$.

Answer (score 1):

$$-0.2^{2019}\times 5^{2020} =\frac{-0.2^{2020}\times5^{2020}}{0.2}= \frac{-(0.2\times 5)^{2020}}{0.2}=\frac{-1^{2020}}{0.2}=\frac{-1}{0.2}=-5$$

Comment: This is a mc question and it says $-5$

Comment: In this case order of operations would tell us that the minus sign is not part of the exponent.

Comment: Note: $$-0.2^{2020}\neq (-0.2)^{2020}$$ So, your answer is wrong.

Comment: Yes It seems a trap question

Comment: @Zaharyas fixed